# Environment variables and repository clones

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mercurial

Reading `HgInit.com` I realized that cloning is a great way to work on experiments. A lot of times, the experiments fail and one wants to go through the original code, and ideally, step through both at the same time to compare values etc. and see what went wrong. With the projects I am working on, this is a problem as they rely on environment variables for paths.

Is there a good workaround that will allow me to work on repository clones with projects that rely on environment variables? I am willing to declare more environment variables as long as it is not error prone and is scalable (that is, if an experiment with clone succeeds, I simply commit without worrying about changing anything relating to environment variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways I tend to approach this sort of situation.

#### Conditional compilation

Sometimes I'll use the existing `DEBUG` symbol or make one of my own and do things like this to replace environment-based configuration:

```
#if EXPERIMENT
    string myVar = "experimental value";
    // or just look up a different envvar
#else
    string myVar = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("myvar");
```

Normal Release/Debug builds won't contain it if you don't declare `EXPERIMENT` anymore in the project settings, and it's easy enough to search for and edit back to normal.

#### Temporary patches

This is the method I prefer for experimental work, however. Conditional compilation will be easier if you've never worked with patches, but cleaning it up to remove the temporary changes takes longer, too.

I enable the `mq` extension in Mercurial and create a new patch for most of the experimental work. I also create a patch on top of that patch for any throw-away changes such as hard-coding a file path or configuration value in order to test something.

HgInit.com doesn't go into patches, but I believe the [Hg Book](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/) does. You will have to be careful of which patch is the topmost applied patch when making changes and remember to `hg qrefresh` to update the patch.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I find it interesting that on the surface it seems to be a very simple solution: Use MY_PROJECT_PATH = C:\MyProjectPath when the main project is loaded otherwise use MY_PROJECT_PATH = D:\MyExpProjectPath when the experimental project is loaded. That would solve all the issues. The patch method you mentioned sounds promising, but considering I will have to change ALL the project files for a changed environment variable path seems excessive. Nonetheless I will look into patches if that is the only way to go.

Comment: You should look into permanently centralizing something, then, if you have to change the same literal value in multiple places. Even if it's the name of the environment variable to grab, it's better if 1 `readonly` field/property or `const` has the actual name and everything else references that.

Comment: That I have done already. In the code, we have it so that it grabs the environment variable from a file and that is available to everyone. The problem is Visual Studio and its include directories. They rely on the environment variable. As you can imagine, having several projects with multiple include directories that use that environment variable may cause problems when the environment variable needs changing.

Comment: I guess these are C++ projects. Patches will track changes to the project files, so if changing the name of the environment variable is possible and only needs to be done once for each project (e.g., from `INCLUDES` to `INCLUDESTEMP`), that's what I'd try. It's also possible to edit some of the XML of project files to do conditional expressions for certain things, but it's not something I'm familiar with.